# Selenium won't drive text into text boxes on a VM

Tags: selenium, webdriver, automated-tests

Writing selenium webdriver code in visual studio in c#.  Have grid hub and virtual machines set up.

So my code sends the job to one of my VMS and loads the browser and webpage just fine.  My "Username.Sendkey" command has worked just fine when running the test locally.  For some reason it won't work on my VM.

I feel like the webdriver completes its run before the page is even fully loaded up and has a chance to enter the user name and password.

Is there a way I can get the webdriver to run and then **WAIT** until the page is fully loaded so it can catch the sendkey commads correctly?

Comment: Have you tried driver.waitforpagetoload()?

Comment: I forgot that WebDriver doesn't have WaitForPageToLoad() since it is supposed to do this automatically.

Comment: You could try waiting for the username and password elements explicitly using WebDriverWait.